# Adding new function to libc

Tags: c, libc

How can I add a new libc function and also call it from C programs? The new function is a not a wrapper to any kernel level system calls. Its function will be done in user space.

Comment: Yes, probably.  But why would you want to?

Comment: This seems a solution to a problem you are facing. How about you share with us what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to add pseudo transactions over the file system interface and as transactions have a transaction begin command, I want to add this as a libc functions.

Comment: This belongs in `liblipkatransactions` not `libc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it in its own library file and link it with `-llibrary_name_here`. The only things that belong in libc are already there (along with plenty of things that don't belong there).